# scriptaculous: onmouseover /onmouseout for several ids and flickering problem

Tags: javascript, function, scriptaculous, onmouseover, onmouseout

Hi so basically what I want to do is to have the same event happen to different images and only write the code line one time in a .js file. This should be very basic but I can't find any easy guide.

This is one sample of the code, and I have this at least 2 times per page:

```
<ul class="car-slide">
        <li onmouseover="$('fp1').fade( {duration:.2, from:1, to:0.8 }); return false;" onmouseout="$('fp1').appear( {duration:.2}); return false;"><img src="{{skin url='myimage1'}}" id="fp1"></li>
        <li onmouseover="$('fp2').fade( {duration:.2, from:1, to:0.8 }); return false;" onmouseout="$('fp2').appear( {duration:.2}); return false;" style="border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #000;"><img src="{{skin url='myimage2'}}" id="fp2"></li>
        <li onmouseover="$('fp3').fade( {duration:.2, from:1, to:0.8 }); return false;" onmouseout="$('fp3').appear( {duration:.2}); return false;"><img src="{{skin url='myimage3'}}" id="fp3"></li>
    </ul>
```

So it's 3 times the same in this list, and I have it twice. I don't know how to do the syntax in the js, and how to refer to it in the html.

Also if you know why the second li has some flickering problems, especially when going fast over it when the first and third one have no problems at all it would be great (might be related to the additional styling but still strange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$$('.car-slide')[0].select('.carsliderfade').each(function(el){
    el.observe('mouseover', function(){ el.fade( {duration:.2, from:1, to:0.8 }); });
    el.observe('mouseout', function(){ el.appear( {duration:.2}); })
})
```

Comment: thanks works great! I am just gonna leave it like that. wanted to put it separately in a js file so it would be loaded one time only, and call the function with an onload or something similar, but that will probably be for when I know what I am doing :)

Comment: you can put the following code in your JS to observe when the DOM is ready: document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { /*code here*/ });

Answer (score 0):

Scriptaculous is an extension to PrototypeJS as far as I know.
So you want to look into that.

If I want to select multiple instances, I give them a CSS class.
Your HTML would look like:

```
<ul class="car-slide" id="carslider">
    <li class="carsliderfade"><img src="{{skin url='myimage1'}}" id="fp1"></li>
    <li class="carsliderfade" style="border-left:1px solid #000;border-right:1px solid #000;"><img src="{{skin url='myimage2'}}" id="fp2"></li>
    <li class="carsliderfade"><img src="{{skin url='myimage3'}}" id="fp3"></li>
</ul>
```

Now I don't know about the animation etc in prototype (I'm a jQuery guy). But here's how to select multiple instances in prototype. It should help you along the way:

```
$('carslider').getElementsByClassName('carsliderfade')....
```

This should select all <li> elements in the given <ul>

Hope it helps

Source: [Prototype API](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!, unfortunately when it comes to JS, I don't know anything. I changed the html and added the css how you mentionned (just shortened the class name) and I tried it with the following code but well it didn't work...                                                                 function carHover ()
{
 document.$('carslider').getElementsByClassName('carsliderfa').each(
 onmouseover = function (el) {
  el.fade( {duration:.2, from:1, to:0.8 }); return false;
 }
 )
}